# Django - Display ImageField

Tags: python, django, imagefield

I've just started to use Django and I haven't found a lot of info on how to display an `imageField`, so I made this:

models.py:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='site_media')
```

views.py:

```
def image(request):
    carx = Car()
    variables = RequestContext(request,{
        'carx':carx
    })
    return render_to_response('image.html',variables)
```

image.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
   <img src=carx />
{% endblock %}
```

I already save an image since terminal and I know is there, also if a do this in image.html:

```
{% block content %}
    {{ carx }}
{% endblock %}
```

The output is: Car object

Can anyone tell me where is my error?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

An `ImageField` contains a `url` attribute, which you can use in your templates to render the proper HTML.

```
{% block content %}
    <img src="{{ carx.photo.url }}">
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Assuming there's a server configured to serve content from `site_media`, anyway.

Comment: I have this in settings.py 

    STATIC_URL ='/Users/gcarranza/PycharmProjects/django_bookmarks/site_media/'


    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/Users/gcarranza/PycharmProjects/django_bookmarks/site_media',
)

Comment: It's more a question of having an actual web server configured - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user shows how you can serve them from Django in development, but that's not a good idea in a production environment.

Comment: Not sure if this is a matter of version, but this approach of providing the variable alone in 'src' doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

You can also make use of the Static URL in Settings.py. Make a directory for example "Uploads", in the Static directory of your app. Also change this in your model in `models.py`.

Use the following code:

```
<img src="{% static carx.photo.url %}" />
```

Comment: Although this would work, you should not upload user files into /static, but into a /media folder.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to all, i fix it in this way.

views.py

```
def image(request):
carx = Car.objects.all()
for mycar in carx:
    MyCar = mycar.photo.url
variables = RequestContext(request,{
    'carx':MyCar
})
return render_to_response('image.html',variables)
```

image.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
     <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ carx }}"/>
{% endblock %}
```

settings.py

```
 MEDIA_URL = '/Users/gcarranza/PycharmProjects/django_bookmarks/'
 STATIC_URL = '/Users/gcarranza/PycharmProjects/django_bookmarks/site_media/'
 STATICFILES_DIRS = (
 '/Users/gcarranza/PycharmProjects/django_bookmarks/site_media',)
```

Now i know that carx.photo.url retrieve the absolute path of the file and its only matter to load as static file.

Comment: @unizeO please update your answer i already did but image not working

Comment: This is more compliated than it really needs to be.