# Python/Django - Get value of a ManyToManyField in a for tag

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-templates, manytomanyfield

I can't get the image related value when I'm using `{% for %}` with the class Article. I tried with select_related, but I don't know how to define image to be correctly in displayed in the `src=""` attribute of my `<img />` tag

Is there a clean way to make appear as I want?

**models.py**

```
    class Image(models.Model):
        gallery = models.ManyToManyField(Gallery)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images/gallery')
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class Article(models.Model):
        section = models.ForeignKey(Menu)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        text = models.TextField()
        type = models.ForeignKey(Type)
        image = models.ManyToManyField(Image)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    slider = Article.objects.all()
    images = Image.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'cms/index.html', locals())
```

**template**

```
{% for i in slider %}
<li>
    <img src="{{i.image}}" alt="{{i.title}}"/>
    <h2>{{i.title}}</h2>
    <p>{{i.text}}, {{i.image_url}}</p>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846290/django-display-imagefield

Comment: Thanks for answer. It is not about how to display the image but more about how to get the content of another class in my loop.

Comment: Please check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use 2 forloop for displaying images in manytomany table.

```
{% for i in slider %}
<li>
    {% for im in i.image.all %}
    <img src="{{im.image.url}}" alt="{{im.name}}"/>
    {% endfor %}
    <h2>{{i.title}}</h2>
    <p>{{i.text}}, {{i.image_url}}</p>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved it perfectly! So if I call the `.all` in a second forloop, it will store all the fields inside the loop to call them?

Answer (score 0):

`Article.image` is a ManyToMany field. Which image You want to display? First?

```
<img src="{{i.image.all.0.image.url}}" alt="{{i.title}}"/>
```

All?

```
{% for im in i.image.all %}
<img src="{{im.image.url}}" alt="{{im.name}}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm trying to display some articles who corresponds to a loop. In this loop I want to display the image related to the article. But the image is in a different class. How can that be done?

Comment: You don't need another class. Everything You need is in `image` field. `image` field is a `QuerySet` which contains all related images.