# Django: loop all the records in a table and then get field from another table

Tags: python, django

I got two class models called Buy and Sell:

```py
class Buy(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.FileField()
    date = models.DateField()
    buy_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    sell_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)



class Sell(models.Model):    
    item = models.OneToOneField(Buy, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    total_paid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(Buyer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.item)
```

In a template, I'd like to display all the records from the Sell table and also the image class-attribute from Buy table.

Below, my view.py:

```py
def sell(request):
    buys = []
    sells = Sell.objects.order_by('-id')
    for sell in sells:
        buys.append(Buy.objects.filter(id=str(sell.item)))
    context = {'sells': sells, 'buys': buys}
    return render(request, 'sell.html', context)
```

Template:

```
        {% for sell in sells %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ sell.item }}</td>
            <td>{{ sell.date|date:'d-m-Y' }}</td>
            <td>{{ buys[0].image}}</td>
            <td>R$ {{ sell.discount }}</td>
            <td>R$ {{ sell.total_paid }}</td>
            <td>{{ sell.buyer }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to do that. I need some help in my view.py!

Comment: Not related, but this `for` loop will become bad quickly. Perhaps try something like this: `buys = sells.select_related("item").values_list("item", flat=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `Buy` entity related to the `Sell` inside the template

```
{{sell.item.image}}
```

If the `image` field is as the name suggests a image you might want to change the field to a `ImageField`.

Then the code to display the image would be:

```
<img src="{{ sell.item.image.url }}">
```

(found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17846328/13168118))

Comment: If `{{ sell.item.image ]}` is in a for loop, use `select_related` on the queryset in the view. Ref [select_related docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related)